# In PHP how do I call the method of an attribute from another class

Tags: php, class, object, methods

I got into a little issue while trying to do some Php object.

I have these classes :

```
class a
{
    public $day;

    function __construct(){
        $this->day = new DateTime("now");
    }
}

class b
{
    public $test;

    function __construct(){
        $this->test = new a()
    }
    function myFunc(){
        $this->test->day->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

I get this error when calling myFunc:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

How could I call from class 'b' the method of an object attribute contained in a class 'a'?

EDIT : Okay so I actually made the above code simpler than what I really have in order to post it here and doing so the error didn't make it through... Here is a code closer to what I have and that displays the error I was talking about

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
class a
{
    public $day;
}

function __construct($day = "now")
{
    $this->day = new DateTime($day);
}

class b
{
public $test;

function __construct(){
    $this->test = new a();
    }   
function myFunc(){
    echo $this->test->day->format("Y-m-d");
    }   
}
$bclass = new b();
$bclass->myFunc();
?>
```

This is exactly what I get when executing it:

> ```
> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\axpo\newPHPClass.php on line 21
> Call Stack
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location
> 1 0.0023  256080  {main}( )   ..\newPHPClass.php:0
> 2 0.0024  257128  b->myFunc( )    ..\newPHPClass.php:25
> ```

I don't understand why it isn't working... I know it's surely something stupid and basic but I just don't see it...

Comment: It works correctly for me if I correct the missing `;` in `b::__construct()` and put an `echo` in `myFunc()`.

Comment: See it at http://codepad.viper-7.com/99vmbE

Comment: You may not be displaying errors, and have encountered something like a missing timezone.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! 

The semi colon was a typo mistake when I tried to come up with a simpler version of my code (which is a little longer than that).

I actually screwed up when trying to made my code simpler to post it here. By screwing up I mean the error got lost apparently. Here is something closer to what I have and that really doesn't work (this time) : 
http://codepad.viper-7.com/qbAfEz

PS: I edited the original post with this new code and the error related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the new code is that you close the class definition after defining **public $day**

> class a {
>       public $day; } // Class gets closed with the last curly bracket !

So the __constructor function isnt called at all !
Delete the curly bracket after "public $day;" and add it after the definition of the __construct function. Then it should work !

Lucian

Comment: Haha, can't believe I got stuck so long on this .
Thank you very much Lucian I was going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semicolon at

$this->test = new a();

and you either have to return or echo the value inside myFunc() of class b to be able to do something with it. Take a look at this:

```
<?php
class a
{
    public $day;

    function __construct(){
        $this->day = new DateTime("now");
    }
}

class b
{
    public $test;

    function __construct(){
        $this->test = new a(); // Added a semicolon !
    }
    public function myFunc(){
       return $this->test->day->format('Y-m-d'); // Return the value
    }
}

$b= new b();
echo $b->myFunc(); // echo the returned value from the function

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Lucian!

The semi colon was a typo mistake I did when trying to come up with an easy to understand version of my code (which is longer than that and with a lot of unrelated stuff)

I actually screwed up when trying to made my code simpler to post it here since apparently the error that I get with mine doesn't apply on what I wrote here and this seems to work perfectly.

But here is something closer to what I have and that really doesn't work (this time) : 
http://codepad.viper-7.com/qbAfEz


PS: I edited the original post with this new code and the error related